# Silverlight on Chromebook

Tags: silverlight, chromebook

In spite of being a dead-end technology, there are a couple of apps built using Microsoft Silverlight that I *have* to use. I'm mostly migrated to using a Chromebook full-time, but these couple of apps are keeping me from going because Silverlight is for Windows or Mac.

What can I do to use these apps with my Chromebook?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Google recommends RDP-ing to a remote machine that can run the silver light code ...

http://support.google.com/chromeos/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1290513

Sucky solution, but there you are.

Answer (score 5):

You can try [IEOnChrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ie-on-chrome/kmomimblkpkjeilfbkinoonalgiejlcl), an extension that emulates IE within Chrome, including Silverlight.

Comment: Works! But unfortunately loads all web pages remotely from a different country, so runs in to country based IP blocking.

Comment: IE On Chrome works great for awhile but it is time and IP limited without a paid subscription.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to get Pipelight installed on your Chromebook.
Probably requires some hacking, but very well worth a try.
Works fine for me on Fedora and Ubuntu:
http://fds-team.de/cms/articles/2013-08/pipelight-using-silverlight-in-linux-browsers.html

Comment: While the link might provide an answer it can quickly become out dated. Can you include the main points from the link within the answer which answer the question. Thanks

Comment: Pipelight ( http://pipelight.net ) lets you run x86 Windows browser plugins in Linux... If you have a an x86 Chromebook and you install regular Linux on it then that should be doable... but many Chromebooks are ARM based and Pipelight only supports x86... you would need to add another x86 emulation layer to start getting things running. (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromebook#Samsung_Series_3 )